# Regular expression: matching part of words

Tags: regex

I want to be able to match several string like "foo" OR "reg" OR "regex".

I know that this is working:

```
(foo|reg|regex)
```

But I would like to know if it is possible to factorize reg and regex, with something like "matching "reg" or "ex" zero or one time after".

Comment: You can use `(foo|reg(?:ex)?)`

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate - thanks anyway (:

Comment: And if I want to match also "regular" ?

Comment: `reg` will find `reg` in `regular`. To match any number of letters after `reg`, use `reg\w*`. To match either `reg`, `regex` or `regular`, use `reg(?:ex|ular)?`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you so much for your quick and detailed answer.

Comment: it's worth noticing that the order of pattern in alternation matters (foo|reg|regex) will match only reg in regex whereas (foo|regex|reg) will match regex.

Comment: @NahuelFouilleul oh, thanks - but why ?

Comment: matching process is an automaton ; in alternation it tries to match in sequential order and only when it fails in a branch it backtrack to next, also when there's a repeated pattern it's like a branch it tries first to repeat (greedy) but this can be changed by quantifier (lazy repeats after backtracking or possessive avoids to backtrack repetition (atomic))